# Galois group of an L-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, abstract-algebra, l-functions

Let  $ M $ be a class of L-functions such that whenever  $ F $ and  $ G $ belong to  $ M $, then so do their product  $ F.G $  and their tensor product  $ F\otimes G $ defined by  $ F\otimes G : s\mapsto\sum_{n>0}\frac{a_{n}(F)a_{n}(G)}{n^s} $ for  $\Re(s)>1 $ if  $ F : s\mapsto\sum_{n>0}\frac{a_{n}(F)}{n^s} $ and  $ G : s\mapsto\sum_{n>0}\frac{a_{n}(G)}{n^s} $ if  $ \Re(s)>1 $ . Suppose also that the constant map  $ s\mapsto 1 $ and the Riemann Zeta function  $\zeta $ belong to  $ M $ .
An automorphism of  $ M $ is a bijection of  $ M $ that sends a primitive element (i.e irreducible for the product) to a primitive element and that commutes to both the usual and the tensor product.

Let's define for an element  $ F $ of   $ M $  and a field automorphism of  $ C $ denoted by  $ \sigma $ the map  $ \Psi_{\sigma} : F\mapsto F_{\sigma}=\sum_{n>0}\frac{\sigma(a_{n}(F))}{n^s} $ if  $ \Re(s)>1 $ .  $ \Psi_{\sigma} $ is an automorphism of  $ M $ .

Let's now define the 'Galois group' of  $ F \in M\setminus\{1,\zeta\}$ as the group  $ \operatorname{Gal}(F) $ , under composition, of field automorphisms  $ \sigma $ of  $ C $ such that  $ F_{\sigma}=F $ . If  $ G\in M $ is such that there exists  $ \sigma $ such that  $ G=F_{\sigma}\neq F $ and  $\operatorname{Gal(F)} =\operatorname{Gal}(G) $ then I managed to prove that this group is abelian. Is it finite ?

Comment: What is an $L$-function, for the purposes of this question?

Comment: Say, an automorphic L-function belonging to the Selberg class. The important thing is that the tensor product of two L-functions is required to be an L-function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M$ be the set of finite products of Dirichlet $L$-functions. These surely form a class of $L$-functions as in the question. Now take some prime $p$ congruent to 1 mod 4 and let $\chi$ be one of the two Dirichlet $L$-functions of conductor $p$ and order 4 (the other one will then be $\overline{\chi}$). Let $F$ be $L(\chi,s)$ and let $G$ be $L(\overline{\chi},s)$. Then $Gal(F)=Gal(G)$ is the automorphisms of the complex numbers which leave $i$ fixed. This group is certainly not finite (indeed it is uncountably infinite). If $\sigma$ is complex conjugation then $G=F_\sigma\not=F$, so there is a counterexample.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but something remains unclear to me. The degree of an element of  $ M $ can be any integer, so how do you prove that  $ F\otimes G $ belongs in  $ M $ whenever  $ F $ and  $ G $ do ?

Comment: You believe it for $F$ and $G$ irreducible because the product of two Dirichlet characters is a Dirichlet character. So then it's true in general because tensor is distributive over product.

Comment: In representation theoretic terms, if $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are representations of a group and they're both a finite direct sum of irreducible 1-dimensional representations, then the same is true of $\rho\otimes\sigma$. Indeed if $\rho\cong\oplus_i\chi_i$ and $\sigma\cong\oplus_j\psi_j$ then $\rho\otimes\sigma\cong\oplus_{i,j}\chi_i\psi_j$.

Comment: It's amazing to see how fast you're able to type...Thank you much anyway. P.S. do you think notions related to this question can be of interest ? I'm becoming doubtful about it.

Comment: I've seen them before in work of Clozel. For an algebraic automorphic representation there should be a coefficient field $E$, a number field in $\mathbb{C}$, and your automorphism group is just the automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ that fix $E$. Clozel used them to prove cohomological representations were arithmetic if I remember correctly, but in some sense this is the standard trick involving the automorphisms of the complexes that everyone uses and it's a pretty coarse invariant.

Comment: Ok. Would you have a link pointing to the considered work of Clozel ?

Comment: I was thinking about his Ann Arbor paper on algebraic automorphic representations for $GL(n)$ from around 1990. But it's just the same trick that went back to Shimura when considering canonical models of Shimura varieties really.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN You should forget automorphisms of L-functions and think to functions on the set of Dirichlet characters...